# Trying to make a magic eightball and my switch statement isn't working

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I've just started doing JS and wanted to make a magic Eightball.

```
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)
let eightball = '';

switch (randomNumber){
  case '0' :
    eightball = 'It is certain';
    break;
  case '1' :
    eightball = 'It is decidedly so';
    break;
  case '2' :
    eightball = 'Repy is hazy try again';
    break
  case '3' :
    eightball = 'Cannot predict now';
    break;
  case '4' :
    eightball = 'Do not count on it';
    break;
  case '5' :
    eightball = 'My sources say no';
    break;
  case '6' :
    eightball = 'Outlook not so good';
    break;
  case '7' :
    eightball = 'Signs point to yes';
    break;
  default :
    eightball = 'yes';
    break;
}

console.log(`The magic eightball said : ${eightball}.`);
```

however it only ever outputs the default. If I take the default out it doesn't output anything.
I know it's probably a syntax error but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: The result of `Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)` is of type number and in your switch statement you are checking for string values.

Comment: ok thx. I thought it was something simple like that.

Comment: Or if you don't want to remove the quotes : ```let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8).toString();```

Comment: I think the question has been answered by the existing answers, but this is probably how I'd deal with the same problem: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/97gcLwfz/), with explanatory comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your `randomNumber` variable is a number, and the switch statement is comparing it to strings.

Here is a fixed version:

```
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)
let eightball = '';

switch (randomNumber){
  case 0:
    eightball = 'It is certain';
    break;
  case 1:
    eightball = 'It is decidedly so';
    break;
  case 2:
    eightball = 'Repy is hazy try again';
    break
  case 3:
    eightball = 'Cannot predict now';
    break;
  case 4:
    eightball = 'Do not count on it';
    break;
  case 5:
    eightball = 'My sources say no';
    break;
  case 6:
    eightball = 'Outlook not so good';
    break;
  case 7:
    eightball = 'Signs point to yes';
    break;
  default:
    eightball = 'yes';
    break;
}

console.log(`The magic eightball said : ${eightball}.`);
```

By the way, `Math.random()` is always less than 1, so `randomNumber` will never equal 8, and the `default` of the switch will never be reached.